# How to save & return data from within Future callback

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, concurrent.futures, lagom

I've been facing an issue the past few days regarding saving & handling data from Futures in Scala. I'm new to the language and the concept of both. Lagom's documentation on Cassandra says to implement roughly 9 files of code and I want to ensure my database code works before spreading it out over that much code.

Specifically, I'm currently trying to implement a proof of concept to send data to/from the cassandra database that lagom implements for you. So far I'm able to send and retrieve data to/from the database, but I'm having trouble returning that data since this all runs asynchronously, and also returning that the data returned successfully.

I've been playing around for a while; The retrieval code looks like this:

```
override def getBucket(logicalBucket: String) = ServiceCall[NotUsed, String] {
request => {
  val returnList = ListBuffer[String]()

  println("Retrieving Bucket " + logicalBucket)
  val readingFromTable = "SELECT * FROM data_access_service_impl.s3buckets;"

  //DB query
  var rowsFuture: Future[Seq[Row]] = cassandraSession.selectAll(readingFromTable)
  println(rowsFuture)

  Await.result(rowsFuture, 10 seconds)

  rowsFuture onSuccess {
    case rows => {
      println(rows)
      for (row <- rows) println(row.getString("name"))
      for (row <- rows) returnList += row.getString("name")
      println("ReturnList: " + returnList.mkString)
    }
  }

  rowsFuture onFailure {
    case e => println("An error has occured: " + e.getMessage)
    Future {"An error has occured: " + e.getMessage}
  } 

  Future.successful("ReturnList: " + returnList.mkString)
 }      
}
```

When this runs, I get the expected database values to 'println' in the onSuccess callback. However, that same variable, which I use in the return statement, outside of the callback prints as empty (and returns empty data as well). This also happens in the 'insertion' function I use, where it doesn't always return variables I set within callback functions.

If I try to put the statement within the callback function, I'm given an error of 'returns Unit, expects Future[String]'. So I'm stuck where I can't return from within the callback functions, so I can't guarantee I'm returning data).

The goal for me is to return a string to the API so that it shows a list of all the s3 bucket names within the DB. That would mean iterating through the Future[Seq[Row]] datatype, and saving the data into a concatenated string. If somebody could help with that, they'll solve 2 weeks of problems I've had reading through Lagom, Akka, Datastax, and Cassandra documentation. I'm flabbergasted at this point (information overload) and there's no clearcut guide I've found on this.

For reference, here's the cassandraSession documentation:

[LagomTutorial/Documentation Style Information with their only cassandra-query example](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/ReadSideCassandra.html)
[CassandraSession.scala code](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/master/persistence-cassandra/scaladsl/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/scaladsl/persistence/cassandra/CassandraSession.scala)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key thing to understand about `Future`, (and `Option`, and `Either`, and `Try`) is that you do not (in general) get values *out* of them, you bring computations *into* them.  The most common way to do that is with the `map` and `flatMap` methods.

In your case, you want to take a `Seq[Row]` and transform it into a `String`.  However, your `Seq[Row]` is wrapped in this opaque data structure called `Future`, so you can't just `rows.mkString` as you would if you *actually* had a `Seq[Row]`.  So, instead of getting the value and performing computation on it, bring your computation `rows.mkString` to the data:

```
//DB query
val rowsFuture: Future[Seq[Row]] = cassandraSession.selectAll(readingFromTable)
val rowToString = (row: Row) => row.getString("name")
val computation = (rows: Seq[Row]) => rows.map(rowToString).mkString

// Computation to the data, rather than the other way around
val resultFuture = rowsFuture.map(computation)
```

Now, when `rowsFuture` is completed, the new future that you created by calling `rowsFuture.map` will be fulfilled *with the result of calling `computation` on the `Seq[Row]` that you **actually** care about*.

At that point you can just `return` `resultFuture` and everything will work as anticipated, because the code that calls `getBucket` is expecting a `Future` and will handle it as is appropriate.

#### Why is `Future` opaque?

The simple reason is because it represents a value that may not currently exist.  You can only get the value when the value is there, but when you start your call it isn't there.  Rather than have you poll some `isComplete` field yourself, the code lets you register computations (callbacks, like `onSuccess` and `onFailure`) or create new derived future values using `map` and `flatMap`.

The deeper reason is because `Future` is a Monad and monads encompass computation, but [do not have an operation to extract that computation out of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))

Comment: You are a goddamn hero. Thank you for an explanation better than any of the 4 places I've been struggling with the past week and a half. Cheers!

Comment: Great answer, sean-vieira!

Comment: Thanks Viktor, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the select for your specific select and the field that you want to obtain for your specific field.The example is only for test, is not a architecture propose.

```
package ldg.com.dbmodule.model

/**
* Created by ldipotet on 05/11/17.
*/

import com.datastax.driver.core.{Cluster, ResultSet, ResultSetFuture}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

//Use Implicit Global Context is strongly discouraged! we must create    
//our OWN execution CONTEXT !
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, _}
import scala.concurrent.duration._


object CassandraDataStaxClient {

//We create here a CallBack in Scala with the DataStax api

implicit def resultSetFutureToScala(rf: ResultSetFuture):    
Future[ResultSet] = {

val promiseResult = Promise[ResultSet]()
val producer = Future {

    getResultSet(rf) match {

       //we write a promise with an specific value   
       case Success(resultset) => promiseResult success resultset
       case Failure(e) => promiseResult failure (new 
                       IllegalStateException)

    }
  }
  promiseResult.future
}

def getResultSet: ResultSetFuture => Try[ResultSet] = rsetFuture => {
    Try(
       // Other choice can be:
       // getUninterruptibly(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws 
          TimeoutException
       // for an specific time

       //can deal an IOException
       rsetFuture.getUninterruptibly
   )
 }

 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def defaultFutureUnit() = TimeUnit.SECONDS
    val time = 20 seconds
    //Better use addContactPoints and adds more tha one contact point

   val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build()
   val session = cluster.connect("myOwnKeySpace")

   //session.executeAsync es asyncronous so we'll have here a 
   //ResultSetFuture
  //converted to a resulset due to Implicitconversion
  val future: Future[ResultSet] = session.executeAsync("SELECT * FROM 
  myOwnTable")

  //blocking on a future is strongly discouraged!! next is an specific     
  //case
  //to make sure that all of the futures have been completed
  val results = Await.result(future,time).all()
  results.foreach(row=>println(row.getString("any_String_Field"))
  session.close()
  cluster.close()
  }
 }
```